# Does logging in with a Skype alias grant access to other Microsoft Account-authenticated services, such as Onedrive?

Tags: security, skype, onedrive

I have recently been subjected to an automated, successful attack from India that managed to gain access to my Skype alias to spam a few links. **I have taken the necessary steps to re-ensure the security of my account.**

> **Note:** My Skype login-alias is from before the Microsoft-Skype era, when you could log-in with a username-password combination instead of an email-password combination.

Is it possible that such a login gained access to my OneDrive account as well, or was it constrained to interaction with Skype only? (such as sending messages)

Comment: Yes;  It's possible (recent chnage) but the password is the same, so if you have 2FA enabled on your MSA you have it enabled on your Skype alias